# Angular Owl carousel with loop clones items out of scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, owl-carousel, owl-carousel-2

I have a directive which render a owl carousel with `loop` option set to `true`. Each item in the carousel is linked to a `ng-click` event. However, as `loop` option is `true`, carousel clones each item into the carousel to give a loop ilusion. These cloned items are not attached to the controller scope.

This is what I'm using

**js**

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.items1 = [1,2,3,4,5];
  $scope.items2 = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10];
  $scope.a = function(i){
    alert(i);
  }
}).directive("owlCarousel", function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        transclude: false,
        link: function (scope) {
            scope.initCarousel = function(element) {
              // provide any default options you want
                var defaultOptions = {
                };
                var customOptions = scope.$eval($(element).attr('data-options'));
                // combine the two options objects
                for(var key in customOptions) {
                    defaultOptions[key] = customOptions[key];
                }
                // init carousel
                $(element).owlCarousel(defaultOptions);
            };
        }
    };
})
.directive('owlCarouselItem', [function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        transclude: false,
        link: function(scope, element) {
          // wait for the last item in the ng-repeat then call init
            if(scope.$last) {
                scope.initCarousel(element.parent());
            }
        }
    };
}]);
```

**html**

```
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <data-owl-carousel class="owl-carousel" data-options="{loop:true}">
      <div owl-carousel-item="" ng-repeat="item in ::items1" class="item">
        <a ng-click="a($index)">{{::item}}</a>
      </div>
    </data-owl-carousel>
  </body>
```

This is a [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/DZ0Q6sRTkP2oeOSq1kAx?p=preview) with the code

**How could I re-render or link scope to the new cloned items?**

Comment: It's a jQuery library which usually means it won't play nice with AngularJS. I ran into many issues like this until I resorted to a different library.

Comment: But is there no a way how can I bind controller scope after rendering? like on jquery using $(".owl-carousel").on('click',function(){});

Comment: did you find a solution finally, I run in similar problems with owl-carousel

Answer (score 1):

The only way to worked was using a $timeout inside of scope.initCarousel function. I know is not the best solution.

Here is the [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/N2sMLVUC5MJ6ComTRf8D?p=preview) fixed

```
.directive("owlCarousel", ['$timeout',function($timeout) {
return {
    restrict: 'E',
    transclude: false,
    link: function (scope) {
        scope.initCarousel = function(element) {
           $timeout(function () {
              // provide any default options you want
                var defaultOptions = {
                };
                var customOptions = scope.$eval($(element).attr('data-options'));
                // combine the two options objects
                for(var key in customOptions) {
                    defaultOptions[key] = customOptions[key];
                }
                // init carousel
                $(element).owlCarousel(defaultOptions);
           },50);
    };
    }
};
```

}])